# T-SQL select sum of Two integer column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I have two columns Val1 and Val2 as int in SQL Server 2008
When I select Tot = Val1+Val2 from Table, I get null as Tot

How do I get total of two int columns selected?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely that you have a null value in one of the columns.  that will produce a null-valued result.

You can do the following, if you want null to represent 0.

```
SELECT Tot = ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0)
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `select Tot = isnull(Val1, 0) + isnull(Val2, 0) from Table`